# How is this JSON coding incorrect?

Tags: javascript, json, object, format

I saw a JSON code on another site as following that was working:

```
var jquerycssmenu={

fadesettings: {overduration: 350, outduration: 100}

...

}
```

So I was writing my own code as following but it didn't work, I don't know why:

```
var CityCountry={
    CityCountryOrigin: {City: Vancouver, Country: Canada}
};
```

Comment: **Never** say "does not work". That doesn't tell anyone anything. Please describe what happens, and how it differs from what you want/need/expect. And if the answer to that is "an error occurs", make that "This exact error occurs: ..." please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it's incorrect. The difference is that values in that 'JSON from another site' are Number literals, but in yours it's (supposed to be) Strings - hence should be quoted, like this:

```
var CityCountry = {
    CityCountryOrigin: {
      City:    'Vancouver', 
      Country: 'Canada'
    }
};
```

Both snippets are not JSON, strictly speaking: they use so-called [JavaScript object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals) instead.

> An object literal is a list of zero or more pairs of property names
>   and associated values of an object, enclosed in curly braces ({}).